# In BPMN 2.0 how do I correctly portray returning to a previous task?

Tags: eclipse, workflow, bpmn

I am trying to create a simple report submission workflow in BPMN. In Eclipse editor I have the following:

[Report submission workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QpyW.png)

Note that in my workflow the user has to resubmit the report if the data is not valid. The problem I have is that Eclipse is telling me Submit Report is incorrect because 'UserTask should have only one incoming Sequence Flow'. However I have found examples of this being done from reliable sources, e.g.  [PyConZA 2012: "Executing BPMN 2.0 workflows in Python" by Matt Hampton](http://slidegur.com/doc/68704/executing-bpmn-2.0-workflows-in-python-%E2%80%93-powerpoint) (see slide 37). Is this just an Eclipse thing or a violation of BPMN format? What is the correct way to portray my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse modeler returns an error message/warning, because Tasks having only one incoming Sequence Flow is considered **good practice**. Still, Tasks with more than one incoming Sequence Flow are syntactically correct/standard-conform.

However, in your example, you need to replace the **Parallel** Gateway with an **Data-based Exclusive Gateway**. Otherwise, the process will be semantically incorrect: In any case both *Submit Report* and *Approve Report* will be executed after *Validate Data*.

Here, you can see a correct example for the general use case of re-executing a task based on a condition/decision:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have also fixed the Gateway. Question about your example though - what is the purpose of the Exclusive Gateway before the task to be re-executed? Why not just connect the backwards arrow directly to the task?

Comment: It's simply more explicit. In the simple processes above, it may feel too verbose. But in a more complex process, a joining Exclusive Gateway helps readers understand the purpose/nature of the join. But as I mentioned: Leaving the joining Gateway out is perfectly valid BPMN. Hint: In contrast to joining an Exclusive Gateway, joining a Parallel Gateway does change the semantics of the process.